# C# return parent class value from child class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am trying to write a Color Theme class that has a main property ForeColor and BackColor (for example). There are several child classes that have other properties, but I want those child classes to return the default ForeColor of its parent class if it's not set.

The idea is that for some specific control colors you can set them if you want otherwise the class will return that I believe is the best alternative.

I am having troubles on accessing the parent class properties and clearly I can't figure this one out, something like this...

```
public class Theme {
  public Color GenericForeColor;
  public Color GenericBackColor;
  public TabControlTheme TabControls = new();

  public class TabControlTheme  {
    public Color ActiveForeColor;
    get => ActiveForeColor == Color.Empty ? parent.GenericForeColor : ActiveForeColor; 
    set => ActiveForeColor = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: So `TabControlTheme` inherits from `Theme`? If so, you need the `: Theme` as part of the class definition.

Comment: After declare `public class TabControlTheme : Theme` you have access to `Theme`'s `GenericForeColor` and `GenericBackColor` public properties. So in `TabCotrolTheme` get part of `ActiveForeColor` may look just like `get => Color.Empty ? GenericForeColor : _activeForeColor` (backing field needs to be introduced)

Comment: I dont want to inherits from Theme on the child, because if I do that the child will also have a GenericForeColor property which I dont want. or at least not publicly

Comment: So make `GenericForeColor` and `GenericBackColor` internal? It's not clear if you want to use inheritance (`TabControlTheme` _is a_ `Theme`) or composition (`TabControlTheme` _has a_ default `Theme`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a constructor the `TabControlTheme` class and pass the parent as an argument.

```
public class Theme 
{
  public Color GenericForeColor;
  public Color GenericBackColor;
  public TabControlTheme TabControls;

    public Theme()
    {
        TabControls = new TabControlTheme(this); // pass this Theme as parent
    }

public class TabControlTheme  
{
    private readonly Theme parent;

    public TabControlTheme(Theme parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));
    }
    public Color ActiveForeColor;
    get => ActiveForeColor == Color.Empty ? parent.GenericForeColor : ActiveForeColor; 
    set => ActiveForeColor = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want inheritance, you need to keep a reference to the parent instance somehow, either through a global singleton instance or when creating the children:

```cs
public class Theme {
  public Color GenericForeColor;
  public Color GenericBackColor;
  public TabControlTheme TabControls = new(this);

  public class TabControlTheme  {

    readonly Theme parent;
    public class TabControlTheme(Theme parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Color ActiveForeColor
    {
      get => ActiveForeColor == Color.Empty ? parent.GenericForeColor : ActiveForeColor; 
      set => ActiveForeColor = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively through a singleton instance (you may need DI for lifecycle, etc):

```cs
public class Theme {
   internal static readonly Theme GlobalTheme = new();

   // ...
   // In your child:
   public Color ActiveForeColor
   {
     get => ActiveForeColor == Color.Empty ? Theme.GlobalTheme.GenericForeColor : ActiveForeColor; 
     set => ActiveForeColor = value;
   }
}
```